# ¿Es posible guardar la cantidad de registros seleccionada en un datable para cuando ingrese de nuevo sea la misma?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Como dice la pregunta, me encuentro buscando alguna forma de poder guardar los registros seleccionados de un databtable, algo así como el permanecer logeado de facebook.

Me explico de mejor forma: si yo veo los registros de una tabla, inicialmente muestro 10, marco la opción y luego selecciono que quiero ver 100 registros.

¿Es posible que cuando actualice la pagina, los 100 registros que seleccione, vuelvan a aparecer?.

Quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: Hola Juan, te animo a mirar el enlace [ask] y crear un [mcve] para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Siempre y cuando la bbdd no cambie y hagas la misma consulta si, es posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
```

Comment: Por favor, mira [answer]. Es importante que pongas contexto a tu respuesta, para que se entienda. Pedazos de codigo suelto no se entienden.

Answer (score 1):

DataTables tiene la opción de poder guardar el estado de una tabla (su posición de paginación, estado de ordenamiento, etc.) para que pueda restaurarse cuando el usuario recarga una página, o vuelve a la página después de visitar una subpágina. Esta capacidad de ahorro de estado está habilitada por la opción stateSave.

El método de ahorro de estado incorporado utiliza las API localStorage y sessionStorage de HTML5 para un almacenamiento eficiente de los datos. Tenga en cuenta que esto significa que la opción de ahorro de estado incorporada no funcionará con IE6 / 7 ya que estos navegadores no son compatibles con estas API. Las opciones alternativas de usar cookies o guardar el estado en el servidor a través de Ajax se pueden usar a través de las opciones stateSaveCallback y stateLoadCallback.

La duración para la cual el estado guardado es válido y se puede usar para restaurar el estado de la tabla se puede establecer usando el parámetro de inicialización stateDuration (2 horas de forma predeterminada). Este parámetro también controla si localStorage (0 o mayor) o sessionStorage (-1) se usa para almacenar los datos.

El siguiente ejemplo simplemente muestra el ahorro de estado habilitado en DataTables con la opción stateSave.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta me ha servido mucho.